# Is there a limit on Highcharts series size?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I use the sankey chart to represent some data and stumbled upon an issue today.

The code sample below embarks two data sets: the `dataJSONfull` which is not displayed correctly, and a subset `dataJSON` (first two elements of `dataJSONfull`) that works.

All code is also [available on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WoJWoJ/yr3xz90o/7/).

Case one (`dataJSON`) is OK:

```js
let dataJSONfull = JSON.parse('[["10.10.90.3","10.10.81.36",5],["10.35.12.8","10.35.24.33",5],["10.40.1.254","10.40.8.151",4],["10.89.7.117","10.89.3.109",4],["10.40.0.126","10.40.8.151",4],["10.6.94.77","10.10.86.5",4],["10.81.102.133","10.10.77.21",3],["10.81.102.133","10.10.86.32",3],["10.81.102.133","10.20.3.91",3],["10.81.102.133","10.85.75.250",3],["10.81.102.133","10.91.114.78",2],["10.10.66.1","10.10.82.0",3],["10.40.15.254","10.40.8.151",2],["10.40.8.175","10.120.0.150",2],["10.40.8.175","10.40.1.15",2],["10.40.8.175","10.40.8.151",2],["10.24.137.61","10.10.77.21",2],["10.24.137.61","10.10.85.1",2],["10.10.68.56","10.10.68.56",2],["10.10.84.3","10.10.86.5",2],["10.10.84.3","10.10.85.1",1],["10.10.86.5","10.10.86.5",2],["10.20.3.91","10.20.3.91",2],["172.16.15.150","172.16.15.150",2],["10.120.0.254","10.40.8.151",1],["10.2.0.1","10.2.0.71",1],["10.40.8.151","10.40.8.151",1],["10.81.99.19","10.91.114.78",1]]')
let dataJSON = JSON.parse('[["10.10.90.3","10.10.81.36",5],["10.35.12.8","10.35.24.33",5]]')
//console.log(dataJSONfull, dataJSON)
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Sankey Diagram'
  },
  series: [{
    keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
    data: dataJSON,
    type: 'sankey',
    name: 'Sankey demo series'
  }]

});
```

```css
#container {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

#csv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sankey.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Case 2 (`dataJSONfull`) breaks with a console error:

```
VM141 sankey.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
    at q.<anonymous> (VM141 sankey.js:22)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at q.createNodeColumns (VM141 sankey.js:21)
    at q.translate (VM141 sankey.js:28)
    at VM140 highcharts.js:289
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at a.Chart.renderSeries (VM140 highcharts.js:289)
    at a.Chart.render (VM140 highcharts.js:291)
    at a.Chart.firstRender (VM140 highcharts.js:294)
    at a.Chart.<anonymous> (VM140 highcharts.js:268)
```

```js
let dataJSONfull = JSON.parse('[["10.10.90.3","10.10.81.36",5],["10.35.12.8","10.35.24.33",5],["10.40.1.254","10.40.8.151",4],["10.89.7.117","10.89.3.109",4],["10.40.0.126","10.40.8.151",4],["10.6.94.77","10.10.86.5",4],["10.81.102.133","10.10.77.21",3],["10.81.102.133","10.10.86.32",3],["10.81.102.133","10.20.3.91",3],["10.81.102.133","10.85.75.250",3],["10.81.102.133","10.91.114.78",2],["10.10.66.1","10.10.82.0",3],["10.40.15.254","10.40.8.151",2],["10.40.8.175","10.120.0.150",2],["10.40.8.175","10.40.1.15",2],["10.40.8.175","10.40.8.151",2],["10.24.137.61","10.10.77.21",2],["10.24.137.61","10.10.85.1",2],["10.10.68.56","10.10.68.56",2],["10.10.84.3","10.10.86.5",2],["10.10.84.3","10.10.85.1",1],["10.10.86.5","10.10.86.5",2],["10.20.3.91","10.20.3.91",2],["172.16.15.150","172.16.15.150",2],["10.120.0.254","10.40.8.151",1],["10.2.0.1","10.2.0.71",1],["10.40.8.151","10.40.8.151",1],["10.81.99.19","10.91.114.78",1]]')
let dataJSON = JSON.parse('[["10.10.90.3","10.10.81.36",5],["10.35.12.8","10.35.24.33",5]]')
//console.log(dataJSONfull, dataJSON)
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Sankey Diagram'
  },
  series: [{
    keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
    data: dataJSONfull,
    type: 'sankey',
    name: 'Sankey demo series'
  }]

});
```

```css
#container {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

#csv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sankey.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

The only difference in the code is the set size but I do not believe this can be the error (not to mention that the code worked yesterday with larger sets).

Both `dataJSON` and `dataJSONfull` are correctly parsed into an Object (so the JSON is fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your larger dataset fails because two lines are self referencing. Specificially

```
["10.10.68.56", "10.10.68.56", 2],
["172.16.15.150", "172.16.15.150", 2],
```

Point `from` and `to` themselves. If you remove them you will get a working code:

```js
let dataJSONfull = JSON.parse('[["10.10.90.3","10.10.81.36",5],["10.35.12.8","10.35.24.33",5],["10.40.1.254","10.40.8.151",4],["10.89.7.117","10.89.3.109",4],["10.40.0.126","10.40.8.151",4],["10.6.94.77","10.10.86.5",4],["10.81.102.133","10.10.77.21",3],["10.81.102.133","10.10.86.32",3],["10.81.102.133","10.20.3.91",3],["10.81.102.133","10.85.75.250",3],["10.81.102.133","10.91.114.78",2],["10.10.66.1","10.10.82.0",3],["10.40.15.254","10.40.8.151",2],["10.40.8.175","10.120.0.150",2],["10.40.8.175","10.40.1.15",2],["10.40.8.175","10.40.8.151",2],["10.24.137.61","10.10.77.21",2],["10.24.137.61","10.10.85.1",2],["10.10.84.3","10.10.86.5",2],["10.10.84.3","10.10.85.1",1],["10.10.86.5","10.10.86.5",2],["10.20.3.91","10.20.3.91",2],["10.120.0.254","10.40.8.151",1],["10.2.0.1","10.2.0.71",1],["10.40.8.151","10.40.8.151",1],["10.81.99.19","10.91.114.78",1]]')
let dataJSON = JSON.parse('[["10.10.90.3","10.10.81.36",5],["10.35.12.8","10.35.24.33",5]]')
//console.log(dataJSONfull, dataJSON)
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Sankey Diagram'
  },
  series: [{
    keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
    data: dataJSONfull,
    type: 'sankey',
    name: 'Sankey demo series'
  }]

});
```

```css
#container {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

#csv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sankey.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

In github, the highcharts team have stated that circular references are not supported as of now: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8218